# Can Ghidra show a function footer in the Listing window

Tags: ghidra

In both IDA and Ghidra have a very nice beginning of function marker text

Ghidra:

```
**************************************************************
*                          FUNCTION                          * 
**************************************************************
```

IDA:

```
; =============== S U B R O U T I N E =======================================
```

what I am struggling with is the lack of end function marker in Ghidra

IDA:

```
; End of function eyefi_cmd_o
```

am I missing a configuration option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may achieve that by choosing: `Edit`->`Tool Options`->`Listing Fields`->`Format Code` and selecting `Flag Function Exits` field.
An example how it works is given below:
[image: ghidraFunctionExit]